# Unreachable code detected in ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I'm getting a "Unreachable code detected" message in Visual Studio 2010 for search method in my ASP.NET app.
This is the method:

```
 public ActionResult SearchIndex(string artist, string albumGenre, string searchString)
    {
        var GenreList = new List<string>();

        var GenreQuery = from d in storeDB.Albums orderby d.Genre.Name select          d.Genre.Name;
        GenreList.AddRange(GenreQuery.Distinct());
        ViewBag.albumGenre = new SelectList(GenreList);

        var ArtistList = new List<string>();

        var ArtistQuery = from a in storeDB.Artists orderby a.Name select a.Name;
        ArtistList.AddRange(ArtistQuery.Distinct());
        ViewBag.artist = new SelectList(ArtistList);

        var albums = from m in storeDB.Albums select m;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(artist))
        {
            return View(albums);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(albums.Where(f => f.Artist.Name == artist));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            return View(albums.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(albumGenre))
        {
            return View(albums);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(albums.Where(x => x.Genre.Name == albumGenre));
        }
  }
```

For this statement I'getting the message:

```
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            return View(albums.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)));
        }
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string artist, string albumGenre, string searchString)
  {
      var GenreList = new List<string>();

      var GenreQuery = from d in storeDB.Albums orderby d.Genre.Name select          d.Genre.Name;
      GenreList.AddRange(GenreQuery.Distinct());
      ViewBag.albumGenre = new SelectList(GenreList);

      var ArtistList = new List<string>();

      var ArtistQuery = from a in storeDB.Artists orderby a.Name select a.Name;
      ArtistList.AddRange(ArtistQuery.Distinct());
      ViewBag.artist = new SelectList(ArtistList);

      var albums = from m in storeDB.Albums select m;

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(artist))
      {
          return View(albums.Where(f => f.Artist.Name == artist));
      }
      else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
      {
          return View(albums.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)));
      }
      else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(albumGenre))
      {
          return View(albums.Where(x => x.Genre.Name == albumGenre));
      }
      else
      {
          return View(albums);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

because in the previous `if-else` block you will surely return and abandon your method, either from the `if` or from the `else` block.

so your following code will never get executed in any case.

Answer (score 1):

The previous `if` has a `return` statement in both of its branches, so your function will always return before reaching that second `if`.